# Error while installing Pillow on Ubuntu

Tags: pip

**DETAILS:**

OS: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Server

vm: VirtualBox 4.1.18

using virtualenv

virtualenv created in the dir, which is shared with win7

**Error**

I execute `pip install Pillow` and get this error:

```
Downloading/unpacking Pillow
  Running setup.py egg_info for package Pillow

    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.hgignore'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.hgtags'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'BUILDME.bat'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'make-manifest.py'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'SHIP'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'SHIP.bat'
    warning: no files found matching '*.html' under directory 'docs'
    warning: no files found matching 'README' under directory 'docs'
    warning: no files found matching 'CHANGES' under directory 'docs'
    warning: no files found matching 'CONTENTS' under directory 'docs'
Installing collected packages: Pillow
  Running setup.py install for Pillow
    error: build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/multiarch: Text file busy
    Complete output from command /home/dizpers/data/www/goodread/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/home/dizpers/data/www/goodread/build/Pillow/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --single-version-externally-managed --record /tmp/pip-ZvMEbN-record/install-record.txt --install-headers /home/dizpers/data/www/goodread/include/site/python2.7:
    running install

running build

running build_py

running build_ext

error: build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/multiarch: Text file busy

----------------------------------------
Command /home/dizpers/data/www/goodread/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/home/dizpers/data/www/goodread/build/Pillow/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --single-version-externally-managed --record /tmp/pip-ZvMEbN-record/install-record.txt --install-headers /home/dizpers/data/www/goodread/include/site/python2.7 failed with error code 1 in /home/dizpers/data/www/goodread/build/Pillow
Storing complete log in /home/dizpers/.pip/pip.log
```

Why it happen so? How to fix? TIA!

**UPDATE**

I figure out the problem  - the problem is that virtual env was created in shared to win7 folder. When I do it in non-shared folde - there is no errors.

Comment: If you have the answer, it's better to post it as an answer and accept it.